# How to enable grouping in the File Structure Window in VS2017

Tags: resharper

I recently installed Resharper 2017.1.3 on Visual Studio 2010 and 2017.
On 2010, the File Structure window has a nice grouping based on categories (private method, public methods, override, etc - see image below). However, in 2017 there is no grouping at all.
I'd like to know if anyone can show me how to enable that in 2017. I tried researching it but couldn't find any solution.

thanks,

[image: Visual Studio 2010]

[image: Visual Studio 2017]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper's structure window doesn't have any grouping functionality as such - it always shows files in the order in which everything is defined. However, it does show regions as groups, as in your first screenshot. Those `EqualsCore` methods are both defined inside a region, and so get grouped by that.

(You'll also notice the little 'x' in the top right of the region grouping box. Click that and ReSharper will remove the region.)